# error message in calender

Tags: asp.net

i am experiencing thi error when i click on the application in the remote machine.

### Server Error in '/please-god' Application.

Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

```
Line 7:      Dim oBF As New BinaryFormatter()
Line 8:      Dim oFS As FileStream
Line 9:      Dim strPath As String = Path.GetTempPath & "schedule.Bin"
Line 10: 
Line 11:     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Source File: D:\Hosting\4423045\html\please-god\appointmentscheduler.aspx.vb    Line: 9

Can someone help me? the full codes for the application is this :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Partial Class appointmentscheduler
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim arrCalendar(12, 31) As String
    Dim oBF As New BinaryFormatter()
    Dim oFS As FileStream
    Dim strPath As String = Path.GetTempPath & "schedule.Bin"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Cache("arrCalendar") Is Nothing) Then
            If (File.Exists(strPath)) Then
                oFS = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Open)
                arrCalendar = DirectCast(oBF.Deserialize(oFS), Array)
                oFS.Close()
                Cache("arrCalendar") = arrCalendar
            End If
        Else
            arrCalendar = Cache("arrCalendar")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        arrCalendar(Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Month, Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Day) = Me.myNotes.Text
        oFS = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create)
        oBF.Serialize(oFS, arrCalendar)
        oFS.Close()
        Cache("arrCalendar") = arrCalendar
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        arrCalendar(Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Month, Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Day) = ""
        oFS = New FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create)
        oBF.Serialize(oFS, arrCalendar)
        oFS.Close()
        Cache("arrCalendar") = arrCalendar
        Me.myNotes.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Protected Sub myCalendar_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles myCalendar.DayRender
        If arrCalendar(e.Day.Date.Month, e.Day.Date.Day) <> "" Then
            e.Cell.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub myCalendar_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myCalendar.SelectionChanged
        Me.myNotes.Text = ""
        If arrCalendar(Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Month, Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Day) <> "" Then
            Me.myNotes.Text = arrCalendar(Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Month, Me.myCalendar.SelectedDate.Day)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

What do i have to do to eliminate this error message?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to open a file that is outside of the web application's root directory. Either move the file into a place where the service account used by IIS has permission to read the file or change the read/write permissions on the file you're attempting to read.

Answer (score 0):

Did you type the error message by hand? `Path.GetTempPath` is a method and should cause a compile error if you don't use the syntax `Path.GetTempPath()`. Makes it hard to dig too deeply into the error messages you've posted if they may not be correct.

Comment: VB.Net doesn't have that requirement. The IDE will add them if you don't, but if they aren't there it will treat it as a method anyway. C# is picky about that sort of thing, but VB allows it.